# Being asked to start teaching before being employed as a new faculty

Tags: united-states, job, tenure-track

I'm going to join a US university as a teaching-focused faculty. My official starting is set to be January 4th and, at that university, classes start in the same week, and I will be teaching 2 courses in my first term.

Things were going smoothly until I received an email from HR informing me that I will need to apply for an SSN upon my arrival in the US, and I will only be able to start working once I receive my SSN by mail, which may take 3-4 weeks. I brought this up with the head of department who then assured me that, yes this is normal, all foreign hires go through the same process, and I can certainly start teaching the courses right away, even if I'm not officially working yet.

I never worked in the US before, but I'm now very confused about this:

As mentioned, I'm expected to start teaching at the university right away even though I'm not actually employed during those first few weeks.

1. Is this indeed the normal process/expectation? Also, is it even legal for the university to ask new hires to start working without putting them on the payroll?
2. Do I risk violating the terms of my H1B visa by "working" without being employed/paid? (I'm probably being paranoid but I heard enough horror stories about the US immigration system...)

(Entering the US before the term starts to apply for the SSN number earlier isn't really an option, as I can only legally enter at most 10 days before the starting date of my visa...)

Comment: Can you ask them for back pay for the work you've done, once you're officially employed?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure they have any mechanisms for doing that (and it wasn't mentioned to me as an option).

Comment: Another thing to worry about is injury coverage. What happens legally if you slip and fall in the classroom and break a leg? (Especially this being in the US with the sad state of their healthcare.) You should definitely be on the books somehow, even if just as an external teacher.

Comment: you need insurance during that time without SSN

Comment: Did the university (or you) not apply for the SSN at the same time as the employment authorization? [It looks like that's one way this could be avoided.](https://www.ssa.gov/ssnvisa/ebe.html)

Comment: @PeterK.: No, apparently they can only do that if I'm already residing in the US.

Comment: Your employer can legally employ and pay you even before you have an SSN by reporting your earnings using a temporary taxpayer identification number, see [here](https://www.zumapay.com/single-post/2017/04/21/can-hire-employee-without-social-security-number/). It sounds to me like either their HR people are incompetent or they are trying to get you to work for free for a few weeks.

Comment: You will almost certainly need to fill out an [I-9, Employment Eligibility Verification](https://www.uscis.gov/i-9) form as part of your employment. I suggest you add the instructions and necessary documents to the list of what you should be prepared for. This is, of course, not the complete requirements of what you'll need, but it's yet another thing which will need to be filled out and may provide you with additional points which you can research.

Comment: I would encourage you to ask this question at https://law.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 12):

I'm not a lawyer, but suggest the following is accurate.

I don't think you have anything to worry about as long as you have a contract, signed and in hand. Tenured and tenure track faculty in US are paid an annual salary, not by the week or month. The SSN is a government requirement that assure your taxes are properly paid and accounted for.

Salaries are normally paid monthly (sometimes twice a month), so your first check might get delayed for a bit since taxes are withheld from it.

But it is really an administrative problem and shouldn't really matter other than a delayed check. Your visa is based on your contract, which you should have.

The Human Resources (HR) office at the university can get you a temporary identification number that will make it all work out for the bureaucracy.

I think any risk is extremely small. The only problem would arise if you couldn't get a SSN for any reason.

Comment: I’m not a lawyer, therefore I don’t give legal advice, and downvote answers by non-lawyers who do.

Comment: @DanRomik, If I'm wrong, then no assistant professor could ever be hired from a different country. Catch 22. You have to start work "immediately" with your visa, but you aren't allowed to start immediately because you don't have and can't get an SSN.

Comment: https://www.zumapay.com/single-post/2017/04/21/can-hire-employee-without-social-security-number/

Comment: @DanRomik, yes, see the TIN section. It will work out.

Comment: @Buffy The TIN section contradicts your answer. OP should not start working without having paperwork finalized and hope it works out. OP should get a temporary TIN, finalize the paperwork, start working, and replace the TIN with an SSN when the SSN is available. More info from an official source: https://www.ssa.gov/pubs/EN-05-10107.pdf

Comment: While this answer is not "wrong" per se, it doesn't really tackles OP's problem: this answer states that OP can start working without an SSN (which is true), but OP was told that the hiring process can only be completed AFTER getting the SSN (which is NOT true), and that it's expected to start teaching BEFORE being officialy hired (which is BAD and potentially a red flag IMO)

Comment: This seems like a "feel good" answer. While things will, probably, work out with diligent investment of time and effort by the question OP, this answer would be *far* better if it provided a list of the documents needed for employment in the US (at least for generic employment in the US; obviously the specific university may have additional requirements) and detailed the exact steps which should be taken to get those documents and any forms which will be necessary to fill out.

Comment: @Makyen, perhaps, but the OP didn't ask for that. They asked for some assurance that the US system isn't so completely screwed up that they would lose their position. I responded to that.

Comment: @Buffy From what I understand, they won't be giving me any temporary number, as they said I should only contact their HR to start the employment process *after* receiving the SSN. While I think you're right that I'm unlikely to lose my job or get deported, it seems to be true that I would be teaching for free for the first month...

Comment: No, salaries are annual, not monthly. If they say you get X per year then you get X. They would have legal troubles otherwise.

Comment: Sorry @Buffy, your answer and the comments you’re posting are hopelessly naive and plain bad advice. Trusting that the department knows what it’s doing and that they will pay OP what OP is due because “they will have legal troubles otherwise” is just a terrible idea. OP should refer the department to the web pages posted showing clearly that the lack of an SSN is no obstacle to getting paid, and insist that the department put them on the payroll from the very first day when they are working. If the department has a problem with that, that’s a massive red flag.

Comment: @DanRomik, you seem to think that the relationship is adversarial, not cooperative. It is in the university's best interest to make it work out. Not every situation calls for the lawyers and strident demands.

Comment: Op, as a new employee, it is not ‘their’ HR, but your HR as well. It would make sense to contact them.

Comment: @Buffy: Even though faculty are paid an annual salary, what matters is the actual starting date. Obviously the OP is not going to be paid the full annual salary given that the OP has a starting date of January, but rather a salary that is adjusted to the actual starting date. I also started mid-year, and my offer letter stated that the salary will be adjusted to the starting date. And if the SSN arrives late that means the OP is going to be earning less. Simple as that.